# How to hide the Angular Material Sidenav when a user clicks a link

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, navigation

I am developing an Angular app that uses Material UI, I used the Angular CLI to generate the following code:

`Navigation HTML`

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
    [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'" [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>
      <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon> Select
    </mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['home']">
        <mat-icon>location_on</mat-icon> - Home
      </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

`Navigation TypeScript`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navigation',
  templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss']
})
export class NavigationComponent {

  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );



  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver) {}

}
```

**My problem is that I want the navbar to close (disappear) when the user clicks on a link.
How do I do that?**
When the user clicks a link, the navbar stays enabled. I have to tap somewhere at the background to make it vanish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you already have a template reference `#drawer` of the sidenav component so you can call toggle method like this

```js
 <mat-nav-list (click)="drawer.toggle()">
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['home']">
        <mat-icon>location_on</mat-icon> - Home
      </a>
 </mat-nav-list>
```

in case we want to toggle the sidebar base of small screen (mobile)

compoenent

```js
  toggle(nav: MatSidenav) {
    const isSmallScreen = this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(
      "(max-width: 599px)"
    );
    if (isSmallScreen) {
      nav.toggle();
    }
  }
```

template

```html
 <mat-nav-list (click)="toggle(drawer)">
      <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="['home']">
        <mat-icon>location_on</mat-icon> - Home
      </a>
 </mat-nav-list>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kyyadi)

Comment: How can I use this and make it mobile-only? I don't want this feature on the desktop. @malbarmavi

Comment: check the updated demo I have create a toggle method for this

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to achieve it with `@ViewChild` I am sharing the code below as I have done it like that.

Selected answer works as well as this one.

**Sharing the code below**

***In your HTML***

```
 <mat-nav-list (click)="closeSidebar();">
  <a mat-list-item >
    Link 1
  </a>
</mat-nav-list>
```

***Inside TS file***

`@ViewChild('drawer', {static: true}) matDrawer: MatSidenav;`

```
closeSidebar() {
   const isHandset= this.breakpointObserver.isMatched(
     "(max-width: 768px)"
   );
   if (isHandset) {
    this.matDrawer.close();
  }
}
```