# Hide Mat Sidebar and Mat Tool bar on specific components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have a simple log-in component just like the pic below:

[image]

I have a mat-sidenav component to navigate through components. This is an example of my mat-sidenav:

```
<mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z8">
<button mat-icon-button *ngIf="sidenav.mode === 'over'" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!sidenav.opened">
        menu
    </mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="sidenav.opened">
        close
    </mat-icon>
</button>
<a routerLink="/home">

    
</a>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container>
<mat-sidenav #sidenav="matSidenav" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    

    <h4 class="name">Juan Perez</h4>
    <p >Chef</p>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <a mat-button class="menu-button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseColaboradores" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseColaboradores">
        <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
        <span>Pacientes</span>
    </a>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseColaboradores">
        <li>
            <a class="nav-links-menu" routerLink="/formulariopaciente/nuevo">

                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i><span class="link-text-menu">Formulario Pacientes</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-links-menu" routerLink="/busquedapaciente/busqueda">

                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="link-text-menu">Ingreso Pacientes</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="nav-links-menu" routerLink="/listapacientes">

                <i class="fa fa-caret-right"></i>
                <span class="link-text-menu">Ingresos Diarios</span>
            </a>
        </li>
       

    </div>        

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <button mat-button class="menu-button">
        <mat-icon>help</mat-icon>
        <span>Help</span>
    </button>

</mat-sidenav>
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <div class="content">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</mat-sidenav-content>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to hide the sidenav and the toolbar when I'm in the login component.  Placing app-sidenav on app.component.html shows the login with both bars (I assume it's because I have the router-outlet inside the mat-sidenav-content) but I don't know another way to achieve this. I actually have 2 components (login and other one) where I need them hidden...I'm trying to think a better way but I don't find any solution :(.

Thanks !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide the Angular Material Sidenav when a user clicks a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61089304/how-to-hide-the-angular-material-sidenav-when-a-user-clicks-a-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i know this amswer might change your folders structure, but i believe this would be better and lowers the overhead, and it's the other way you're looking for i guess.

I suggest to place all `login`, `sign up`, `forgot password`, etc.. components in a seperated module, call it `AuthModule`.

And make a shared module for `app-header`, `app-sidenav`, `app-footer` components, call it `SharedModule`.

(You can organize this even more by creating a component for each sidenav anochor tag *or a link*)

Now make a module name it `HomeModule`, create your components, and just call the 3 tags you made in the `SharedModule` in all required pages.

Here are couple of basic snapshots.

[Folders Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Mjs.png)

[Usage of Shared Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UKb1.png)

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks man, I've tried this and it worked. I had to change the router-outlet for ng-content and place the sidenav where I need it. Now, I want to disable the sidenav animation because every time a click a nav, the sidenav shows its animation and looks 'weird'.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of animation looks weird when clicking a nav item, but here's a working demo for disabling sidenav animation.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6enqwb-yxaggq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-autosize-example.ts